# Sending email via Android App needs permissions?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-permissions

I need to use the email feature when the user of my app need to send any feedback to developer. I am going to use the below code. I wonder if this needs any permission setup in Manifest file.

Please advice, If this needs any permission that has to be setup in Manifest file

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I checked and no, you don't need any permissions setup in `AndroidManifest.xml` to send email.

Answer (score 1):

your code does not need any permission for sending email but if you want to send email using libraries like `mail.jar` you must add Internet permission to the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

No, You don't need any permission to send email using intent.